# Keyboard Shortcut Error

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I Have not had any updates/changes to computer and now all of the sudden my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcuts are no longer working. The individual keys seem to be working like for example I can use cut/paste shortcuts.

What could cause this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work for me. Have you tried them inside the Windows Explorer, the desktop and apps? Are you **completely** shure you didn't even install anything new? afaik the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> shortcut has interrupt priority so it mustn't be blocked/mapped by anything. Maybe an update or a rollback (restore to a previous state, if you can) could work.

Good luck.